# Cross Join for calculation in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a temporary view with only `1` record/value and I want to use that value to calculate the age of the customers present in another big table (with `100`M rows). I used a `CROSS JOIN` clause, which is resulting in a performance issue.

Is there a better approach to implement this requirement which is will perform better ? Will a `broadcast` hint be suitable in this scenario ? What is the recommended approach to tackle such scenarios ?

Reference table: (contains only `1` value)

```
create temporary view ref
as
select to_date(refdt, 'dd-MM-yyyy') as refdt --returns only 1 value
from tableA
where logtype = 'A';
```

Cust table (10 M rows):

```
custid | birthdt
A1234  | 20-03-1980
B3456  | 09-05-1985
C2356  | 15-12-1990
```

Query (calculate age w.r.t `birthdt`):

```
select 
a.custid, 
a.birthdt, 
cast((datediff(b.ref_dt, a.birthdt)/365.25) as int) as age
from cust a
cross join ref b;
```

My question is - Is there a better approach to implement this requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: Reference table 1 value - but how many other values?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `withColumn`!

```
df.withColumn("new_col", lit("10-05-2020").cast("date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside view you are using `constant` value, You can simply put same value in below query without cross join.

```
select 
a.custid, 
a.birthdt, 
cast((datediff(to_date('10-05-2020', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), a.birthdt)/365.25) as int) as age
from cust a;
```

```
scala> spark.sql("select * from cust").show(false)
+------+----------+
|custid|birthdt   |
+------+----------+
|A1234 |1980-03-20|
|B3456 |1985-05-09|
|C2356 |1990-12-15|
+------+----------+
```

```
scala> spark.sql("select a.custid, a.birthdt, cast((datediff(to_date('10-05-2020', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), a.birthdt)/365.25) as int) as age from cust a").show(false)
+------+----------+---+
|custid|birthdt   |age|
+------+----------+---+
|A1234 |1980-03-20|40 |
|B3456 |1985-05-09|35 |
|C2356 |1990-12-15|29 |
+------+----------+---+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I used the hard-coding only to simplify this example. However, in the real world, the value in that table is being pulled from another table. That's why we built a view on top of it. I have updated the question with the actual View definition. Pls take a look and let me know your comments

Answer (score 0):

Hard to work out exactly your point, but if you cannot use `Scala` or `pyspark` and `dataframes` with `.cache` etc. then I think that instead of of using a `temporary view`, just create a single row `table`. My impression is you are using Spark %sql in a notebook on, say, Databricks.

This is my suspicion as it were.

That said a `broadcastjoin` hint may well mean the optimizer only sends out 1 row. See https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-hint-framework.html#specifying-query-hints

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I use Spark Sql queries to inspect/query data in a table from `sql workbench`.. I generally break up an otherwise large query into sub-sets of temporary views and then finally merge them in the final step. So my question is - given the above requirement does my implementation looks ok ? Also, is it ok to broadcast (hint) the small temp view in the `cross join` to achieve better results ? thanks

Comment: Yeas, I think you are right. That would most likely force  the single row to be sent. In the dataframe api approach easier to check. Modded answer as it is an oversight we have all made. You note most of us here use scala or pyspark.